# DB2, Trying to Insert a new record and deleting an old one in the same transaction

Tags: sql, join, db2, sql-update, sql-delete

Suppose I have a table with like so TABLE1:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Field Type         |         ID       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         342      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         343      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         344      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And a temp table like so TABLE2:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Field Type         |         ID       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         342      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         3455     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         344      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want the Table1 to have the same data as Table2. So essentially i want to update the record with field type 2. Ideally I would like to Delete the record with field type 2 from TABLE 1 and Insert the Field type 2 record from Table 2.

I don't want to delete the whole table and just replace it with the table 2 info, I don't want to touch the records that have the same info in both tables. I wish to only delete the records in Table 1 that are different from Table 2 and replace it with the info from TABLE 2  which pertains to that specific field type.

I tried inserting the new record anyways and then going back and deleting like such:

```
          DELETE FROM (
  SELECT FIELD_TYPE, ID FROM TABLE1
    WHERE EXISTS (select * from TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2 .FIELD_TYPE = TABLE1 .FIELD_TYPE AND TABLE2.ID != TABLE1.ID)
 );
```

but it gave me some performance issues. I was wondering if it's possible to do this with a single transaction.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello. It looks like you could benefit from a cursor. A Transaction will make changes to the table in an all-or-nothing fashion.

Answer (score 0):

For your dataset, an `update` query  should do it:

```
update table1
set id = (select id from table2 t2 where t2.field_type = table1.field_type)
```

You can be more specific by filtering on records that need to be updated only:

```
update table1
set id = (select id from table2 t2 where t2.field_type = table1.field_type)
where id <> (select id from table2 t2 where t2.field_type = table1.field_type)
```

Depending on your DB2 vendor, you could also use the `merge` syntax:

```
merge into table1 t1
using table2 t2
on (t1.field_type = t2.field_type and t1.id <> t2.id)
when matched then update set id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have considered this, but the problem is that TABLE1 has Child tables that are dependent on Deletes and Insert to that table. Which is why I would like to have something that Deletes then inserts, or Inserts then deletes.

Comment: I have also tried the Merge syntax, but the NOT MATCHED clause didn't like the Update clause.  Kept throwing an error stating the  UPDATE clause isn't expected.